# ARCore support for newly released terminals

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

I did a search on ARCore-enabled devices.

https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

It doesn't say whether it will support the Galaxy Tab S5E.

Will ARCore work on the Galaxy Tab S5E?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there's no `Samsung Galaxy Tab S5E` in a list of ARCore-supported devices because it's new – Google did not have a time to update a list.

> But I'm 99% sure it'll be on a list because `Samsung Galaxy Tab S5E` has all the required sensors for AR experience: **Gyroscope**, **Accelerometer**, **back RGB camera** and **Magnetometer**.

Why not 100%? Because business policy and hardware issues are unpredictable things.